# Generating dummy variable if point lies inside polygon using QGIS

Tags: qgis, geojson, overlapping-features, point-in-polygon, boolean

I have a set of polygons in JSON or GeoJSON format and a set of points in a CSV (both containing geographic coordinates). I am able to join these two datasets in QGIS and display them.

I want to generate a dummy variable equal to `1` if a point lies inside a polygon and to `0` if it does not.

The `'Points in polygon'` function in QGIS does not help me with regard to this.

Comment: You'll probably have to convert your data to a different format like shapefile or even sqlite so you can do some sql CASE statements using spatial functions to set these... then write the data back out to geojson for your web project...

Answer (score 3):

The solution has been provided by @DPSSpatial already, but let me try to demonstrate a `Virtual Layer` approach (hence `sqlite`, as commented by DPSSpatial ):

### Example

Please consider some elephants were observed in and out of the Singapore zoo. I would like to mark elephants "inside a green fence".

[image]

- Elephants: point layer  -- loaded as csv through Delimited text layer.
- zoo: polygon layer (green)  -- loaded as geojson file.

**Virtual Layer**

(1) `Layer | Add Layer | Add/Edit Virtual Layer`

(2) Import `Elephants` and `zoo` layers

(3) Give a query like below:

```sql
SELECT Elephants.*, st_within(Elephants.geometry, zoo.geometry) AS dummy
FROM Elephants, zoo
WHERE st_within(Elephants.geometry, zoo.geometry)
```

We will get something like:

[image]

Oh, sorry you wanted a complete list of [1, 0] in the dummy column... Then remove *WHERE* (filter) from the above query, i.e.:

```sql
SELECT Elephants.*, st_within(Elephants.geometry, zoo.geometry) AS dummy
FROM Elephants, zoo
```

[image]

You will obtain a full listing in the **dummy** column.