# Identify if the point lies inside the polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, overlapping-features, point-in-polygon, within

I created a polygon using Iso-Area as polygons algorithm in QGIS. I have a point's coordinates and added it as a vector layer into QGIS. It is shown on the map that the point lies within the polygon. Then I wanted to create a dummy variable that indicates that the point lies inside the polygon. Using what I found in the following link I created a Virtual Layer by applying this query (`'A'` is the point layer and `'B'` is the polygon layer):

```sql
SELECT A.*, st_within(A.geometry, B.geometry) AS dummy
FROM A, B
```

But the value of the created dummy variable is `0`, while the point is inside the polygon. What is the solution?

[Generating a dummy variable if point lies inside a polygon using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228464/generating-a-dummy-variable-if-point-lies-inside-a-polygon-using-qgis)

Comment: Do both layers use the same CRS? Are you 100 % sure the point is within the polygon? Sometimes points close to the border look like they are inside at a certain scale. Can you provide an image showing the point and polygon in question?

Comment: @Erik Both layers did not have the same CRS. After resolving this, the problem solved

Comment: As far as I remember SQL cares about CRS way more than QGIS does ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the field calculator for your point layer and add a new **virtual** field, set the field type to whole number, and add the following expression (swap out `'polygons'` for the name of your polygon layer in single quote marks):

`intersects($geometry, aggregate('polygons', 'collect', $geometry))`

This expression aggregates all features of the polygon layer into a single multipart geometry and then checks if the point intersects that multipart polygon.

A result of 1 means it does intersect.

Comment: The problem was because of not having both layers in the same CRS. After figuring out this, your solution as well as the solution that I mentioned in my question worked.