# Creating field with 1/0 values depending if point sits inside polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, field-calculator, point-in-polygon, qgsexpression

I have a layer with a single polygon and a layer with multiple points. Some of the points are inside the polygon. How can I create/update a field with a value of 1 (true) or 0 (false) depending if a point is inside the polygon.

[Example from a similar question here.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228464/generating-dummy-variable-if-point-lies-inside-polygon-using-qgis)

I need to use this as part of a field calculator step in a graphical model. I've got scraps of code but I can't get the syntax for intersect expression right:

```
intersects(geometry('points'), geometry('polygon'))
```

I imagine using that along with some form of:

```sql
CASE
    WHEN
END
```

See below image for the problem:

[image: Point in polygon]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this expression: `overlay_within('polygon')` (see below for alternatives):

[image]

Just for your curiosity: the syntax for the `intersects` function is like this (returning 0/1):

```
intersects(
    $geometry,
    aggregate(
        'polygon',
        'collect',
        $geometry
   )
)
```

or:

```
intersects(
    $geometry,
    geometry (
        get_feature_by_id(
        'polygon',
        1)))
```

Comment: Thank you for the syntax clarification, that's great. Also thanks for Overlay_within, it works perfectly as a standalone process. Unfortunately it does not seem to work with the Field calculator in the graphical modeler. Instead, all the results of my "Within" field are 0 at the end of my modeler process. Any ideas?

Comment: Which QGIS version do you use? the overlay functions work formQGIS 3.16 on

Comment: I use 3.16. The overlay function works outside the graphical modeler, but it doesn't seem to work inside the modeler.

Comment: Does the intersects expression work in the modeler? Maybe you should ask another question here for this problem.

Comment: Does and will not work in modeler because you cannot reference a layer in expressions using the modeler. See https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/30397#issuecomment-505699624

Comment: Thanks for the reponses. Am I to understand that this task will require a custom processing script/plugin?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution that uses the [`CASE`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#case) statement

```sql
CASE
    WHEN overlay_intersects('test2') THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END
```

[image: result]

p.s. *'test2'* is the name of the polygon layer

---

I think that the `CASE` statement is useful when there are many conditions that have to be applied, if there are just two i.e. true/false, use the [`if`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#if) condition instead, like:

```
if(overlay_intersects('test2'), 1, 0)
```

---

I will most likely use the solution provided by @Babel, however, when 1/0 is required instead of true/false, adjust the expression accordingly:

```
to_int(overlay_within('test2'))
```