# How to perform intersect or overlay_within functions using Python/PyQGIS to circumvent graphical modeler limitations?

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, pyqgis-3, point-in-polygon

This relates to [Creating field with 1/0 values depending if point sits inside polygon in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/418918) for which people provided excellent answers but unfortunately highlighted a current limitation of the graphical modeler: [layer based expressions cannot access temporary layers inside the graphical modeler.](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/30397)

To navigate around this setback I have decided to bring my model into a python script which I will try to convert to a plugin, treating the whole thing as a learning project.

Being relatively green with coding, could someone drop some hints at how I could construct a custom processing script to perform either an intersect(within) or overlay_within query, and is it possible to refer to layers created temporarily during the process in this custom script?

The original problem: *I have a layer with a single polygon and a layer with multiple points. Some of the points are inside the polygon. I'd like to create/update a field with a value of 1 (true) or 0 (false) depending if a point is inside the polygon.*

[image]

Comment: For PyQGS please provide some code ^_^

Comment: I would say there is a bit of a learning curve to writing your own processing scripts, but they are pretty straight forward (and very powerful) once you start to get your head around how they work. Did you know you can export a model as a Python script (use the 'Export as Script Algorithm...' tool button in the model designer. This will create all the boiler plate and write 90% of your code for you! You would then need to modify the script to add a spatial test on the points and set an attribute to 1 if point is within polygon or 0 if not.

Comment: I have chucked a bit of an example into a github gist here which does something similar to what you want and should give you some hints. https://gist.github.com/benwirf/310331cd80e6a9ae123633c9b5cf6206