# Creating a dummy to identify if a point lies within a polygon using Python

Tags: python, geopandas, point-in-polygon

I have two Geopandas (two shapefiles), one is a polygon type, and the other is a point type. I would like to create a new column in the geopanda of polygon type with a dummy variable saying 1 if there is at least one point inside the polygon and 0 otherwise.

I have looked last questions and this question has been answered for QGIS. For example, here [Creating field with 1/0 values depending if point sits inside polygon in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/418918/creating-field-with-1-0-values-depending-if-point-sits-inside-polygon-in-qgis) or here [Generating dummy variable if point lies inside polygon using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228464/generating-dummy-variable-if-point-lies-inside-polygon-using-qgis). However, I have not seen how to do it using Python.

According to the answers in QGIS, I have tried to do, among other things, the following:

```
import geopandas

polygon['dummy'] = geopandas.overlay(polygon, point, how='intersection')
```

where polygon and point are my shapefiles. It says *"Value Error: Expected a 1D array, got an array with shape (12431,9)"*. Any idea about the error? Should overlay a good way to do it or any other proceed could be better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use spatial join

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np

poly = gpd.read_file(r'D:\temp_diverse\polygons.shp')
point = gpd.read_file(r'D:\temp_diverse\points.shp')

df = gpd.sjoin(poly, point[['geometry']], how="left") #Join the points to the polygons
df['point_present'] = np.where(np.isnan(df['index_right']), 0, 1) #The column 'index_right' will be nan if there are no points
del(df['index_right']) #The point index column is no longer needed.


#df.loc[df.id.isin((76,84))]

#      id  ...  point_present
#75  76.0  ...              0
#83  84.0  ...              1
```

[image]